# Timer server-side?

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, websocket

Estou fazendo um jogo de perguntas em PHP, o usuário terá 15 segundos para responder cada pergunta, como evitar que o usuário altere o timer via inspecionar elemento e adicione segundos?

Apenas adicionando detalhes, é inviável deixar que o usuário altere o tempo de 15 para 50 segundos por exemplo e verificar se o tempo bate via PHP pois quero implementar o jogo para que 2 usuários joguem simultaneamente, então, os dois teriam 15 segundos e avançariam as perguntas juntos.

Comment: Qual a linguagem no servidor? PHP ou Node.js? Qual o código no lado do cliente que tens receio que o utilizador manipule? podes mostrar o código que tens?

Comment: Validando no lado do servidor também. Não se esqueça de dar uma pequena tolerância para compensar a demora da requisição, afinal, se o usuário alterar o timer, o tempo que ele gasta pra isso vai dar uma diferença grande. Ao enviar a pergunta, guarde no servidor o momento do envio, ao processar a resposta, veja se levou mais que vinte segundos, por exemplo.

Comment: PS: falei vinte como exemplo, na verdade o ideal seria analisar dinamicamente a demora das requisiçoes e ajustar de acordo, para não facilitar nem pra quem tem um _bookmarklet_ de trapaça, e não prejudicar quem tem um link lento. Ou usar um protocolo mais "chato" pra isso, por exemplo, pergunta e resposta via _websockets_, assim o tempo seria controlado só no servidor.

Comment: Sergio, no servidor vou usar PHP, ainda não tenho nenhum código pronto, antes de começar a programar queria a solução desse problema.

Bacco, mas se eu fizer isso, nada impede do jogador alterar o tempo disponível via inspecionar elemento.

Comment: Qual código você tem até o momento?

Answer (score 0):

Talvez você possa guardar do lado do servidor o horário (timestamp) em que a pergunta foi mandada e depois comparar com o horário em que a resposta foi enviada.

Caso a diferença seja menor do que o seu limite (com uma gordurinha pra questões de latência de rede), você aceita a resposta. Caso contrário (ou seja, se a diferença for maior do que o aceitável), não aceita e devolve um erro.

Desse modo o contador do lado do cliente passa a ser apenas uma visualização, mas a sua validação fica segura do lado do servidor.

Answer (score -1):

Faz isso fora da pagina, cria um arquivo só para isso, e nele mesmo guarda a informação do tempo passando, então quando o usuário mudar no inspecionar clemente, o valor que ele digitar, independente de qual,voltara ao normal de acordo com a variável do teu arquivo, e inclusive, pode fazer um script para verificar se foi alterado pelo usuário e seila, desclassifica-lo do seu jogo

Comment: Não entendi sua ideia.

Comment: timer = 5; // segundos
$("#elemento").text(timer);

var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
 var estadoatual = $("#elemento").text();
 if( estadoatual == timer ){
  timer--;
  $("#elemento").text(timer);
 }else{
  //o que acontece se o usuário tentou trapacear
  console.log("Timer alterado pelo usário")
  clearInterval(interval);
 }
 if( timer == 0){
  clearInterval(interval);
  fimdotempo();
 }
}, 1000);

function fimdotempo() {
 //codigo para fim do tempo
 console.log("Fim do tempo");
}

Comment: Isso não resolve o problema, basta mudar a variável timer e terá o cenário que eu comentei.

Comment: Ai o usuário so vai conseguir mudar o timer se você almentar de 1000 para seila, uns 5000, e se ele alterar a contagem para, e tem ali um espaço para você decidir o que acontece se isso acontecer

Comment: poêm isso em um arquivo timer.js e chama na tua pagina

Comment: Valim, de qualquer modo, o usuário pode alterar, basta ele deletar a parte que inclui o arquivo timer.js e modificar. JavaScript do lado do client não me parece uma solução.

Comment: excluir o arquivo nao para o codigo, e não adianta ele mudar no lado do cliente, não muda o contador, se ele conseguir mudar a contagem para, testa ai e ve

Comment: mesmo excluindo o contador da pagina o codigo nao parar de rodar, e no fim ele vai passar